# DocuSign non-expired OAuth token

Tags: api, docusignapi

I am working on **docusign** Api integration for that i am looking in [API Explore by DocuSign.](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com)

From ther to Sandox access I am seeing **DocuSign non-expired OAuth token.** How can i get that? 
or

How can I create **DocuSign non-expired OAuth token?**
[image]

### **Question**:

How can I create/get **DocuSign non-expired OAuth token?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Explorer's UX could be improved. To use the tool, just click the **Get OAuth2 Token** button.

You don't need to supply anything in the Access token field.

Comment: First of all don't change my question.

Comment: I'm asking for how to get non-expired OAuth token? I know click the *Get OAuth2 Token* button I'm authenticated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Are you asking how do you programmatically get an OAuth Access Token? You use the OAuth protocol for that. See the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication)

Comment: Sorry for delay, My question is
**How can I create DocuSign non-expired OAuth token?**

Comment: All DocuSign OAuth tokens eventually expire. The API Explorer is (optionally) asking for a token that is still active. It is not asking for a token that never expires.

Comment: Got Your Point, Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user8719510
Did you find any way to generate DocuSign non-expired OAuth token.
when i try to generate OAuth token using api i need to generate auth code before to get token but auth code  is expiring for every 2 minutes and it is manual process by creating a url with redirect url.

Comment: @rameshm All DocuSign access tokens expire after either 1 hour or 8 hours, depending on how you obtained the access token. The 2 minute timeout is a part of the OAuth flow and should never be an issue. If it is an issue, then you have not implemented the OAuth flow correctly.